# Error: Main method not found in class Binary, please define the main method as: public static void main(String[] args)

Tags: java

When I exercised an example code of Algorithms(by Sedgewick), I tried to run that. The execution in Eclipse failed with following error message:
*Error: Main method not found in class Binary, please define the main method as: 
public static void main(String[] args)*

The DrJava shows:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at BinarySearch.main(BinarySearch.java:61)
```

I think there must be something wrong with this line `In in = new In(args[0]);`.

The source code is :

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class BinarySearch {

    public static int rank(int key, int[] a) {
        int lo = 0;
        int hi = a.length - 1;
        while (lo <= hi) {
            // Key is in a[lo..hi] or not present.
            int mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;
            if      (key < a[mid]) hi = mid - 1;
            else if (key > a[mid]) lo = mid + 1;
            else return mid;
        }
        return -1;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // read in the integers from a file
        In in = new In(args[0]); 
        int[] whitelist = in.readAllInts();

        // sort the array
        Arrays.sort(whitelist);

        // read key; print if not in whitelist
        while (!StdIn.isEmpty()) {
            int key = StdIn.readInt();
            if (rank(key, whitelist) == -1)
                StdOut.println(key);
        }
    }
}
```

PS: "In","StdOut",and "StdIn" are three external libraries, and have been imported successful. 
and the line 61 in the first error display is this line " In in = new In(args[0]); "

The part defined in.readAllInts() is following:

```
/**
 * Read all ints until the end of input is reached, and return them.
 */
public int[] readAllInts() {
    String[] fields = readAllStrings();
    int[] vals = new int[fields.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++)
        vals[i] = Integer.parseInt(fields[i]);
    return vals;
}
```

Comment: class `Binary` is not `BinarySearch`

Comment: You may have renamed your Main class without changing Eclipse *Run configuration*.

Comment: What arguments do you pass to `BinarySearch` ?

Answer (score 0):

When you access the first command line argument with

```
args[0]
```

your program will die in the way you described when there are no arguments.

Thus, always check the presence of the arguments you expect:

```
if (args.length == 0) {
    System.err.println("Please supply command line arguments!");
}
else {
   // your program logic here
}
```

Comment: I did the modification you suggested,but it still doesn't work, some error display. by the way, this program was not written by me, it's the example program of that book, that is to say,the error must exist in somewhere the author thought it's too simple to present.

Comment: Yeah, this is very bad, as I can solve many errors, but not **some error**.

Comment: thanks, anyway. I finally found out where the error is, i run that program by click the "RUN" button on GUI,while i should have run it in console, so that i can appoint the arguments of main().